# Optimal inversion counting on int arrays

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

Today I was looking the latest exam of the local informatics olympiad and I found a interesting problem. Briefly, it asks to, given an integer array, count how many inversions it has, where an inversion is a pair of indicies `i`, `j` such that `i > j` and `A[i] < A[j]`. Informally, the number of inversions is the number of pairs that are out of order. Initially I made a `O(n²)` solution (yes, the naive one), but seeing it wouldn't fit well with the size of the input, I thought about the problem a bit more and then I realized it's possible to do it within `O(n log n)` time by a variant of merge sort, which handles good the size of the input.

But seeing the input constraints (`n` integers between `1 and M`, and no duplicates), I was wondering if my solution is optimal, or do you know if is there any other solution to this problem that beats `O(n log n)` runtime?

Comment: What's an inversion?  I see the term crop up elsewhere in relation to arrays, but can't quite glean the meaning.

Comment: OK - found the answer to my own question - for array A, If A[i] > A[i + j] where j > 0, A[i] and A[j] are an inversion.  Just a fancy term for two elements that are "out of natural order" wrt. each other.

Comment: Oh, sorry, maybe I should have explained about it.

Comment: What would be better than O(n log n) in the world of computing, short of O(n)?

Comment: @Luiz - no problem, judging from other posts I'm the only one that doesn't (didn't!) know what it means!

Comment: Yeah, maybe a non comparison-based one, but I couldn't figure how.

Comment: What are the limits on n and M? It's possible to do with an algorithm similar to counting sort in `O(n * M)`, but it's doubtful it's going to beat the `O(n log n)` algorithm.

Comment: 1 <= n <= M <= 10^6. In this case it would be no better than the quadratic algorithm ):

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best result in the literature is an O(n √(log n)) algorithm due to [Chan and Patrascu](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mip/papers/invs/paper.pdf). No idea about the constant.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought the inversion problem had the same lower bound as sorting, so in this case where there are many linear algorithms available for sorting the same would do with the inversion. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

O(n log n) is the best as far as I know.

A detailed explanation was given here:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the number of bits used to represent the integer is constant (say 32 or 64 bits), this can be solved in O(N) time.

Here is an example python implementation.

http://ideone.com/g57O87

```
def inv_count(a, m=(1<<32)):
  if not m or not a:
      return 0
  count = 0
  ones = []
  zeros = []
  for n in a:
    if n & m:
      ones.append(n & ~m)
    else:
      count += len(ones)
      zeros.append(n & ~m)
  m /= 2
  return count + inv_count(ones, m) + inv_count(zeros, m)
```

print inv_count([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print inv_count([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

We are able to achieve less than O(N x Log(N)) time complexity, as we are using idea behind a non-comparative sorting algorithm, radix sort, to get the count.